# Kendo treeview with checkboxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using a Kendo UI tree view with check-boxes for an MVC Razor application and the problem with this is , when i unchecked a child node the parent node is not unchecked. But when the parent node is checked all the child nodes is checked automatically. 
any help is appreciated.

```
 @{Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                    .ExpandAll(false)
                    .Name("PrivelegeTreeView")
                    .Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes
                               .Name("checkedFiles")
                               .CheckChildren(false)
                                )

                    .BindTo(ViewBag.TreeViewModel as IEnumerable<Kendo.Mvc.UI.TreeViewItemModel>, mappings =>
                    {
                        mappings.For<Kendo.Mvc.UI.TreeViewItemModel>(binding => binding
                                .ItemDataBound((item, roleItem) =>
                                {
                                    item.Text = roleItem.Text;
                                    item.Id = roleItem.Id;
                                    item.Checked = roleItem.Checked;
                                })
                                .Children(a => a.Items));
                        mappings.For<Kendo.Mvc.UI.TreeViewItemModel>(binding => binding
                        .ItemDataBound((item, roleItem) =>
                        {
                            item.Text = roleItem.Text;

                        }));
                    }).Render();
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had to write a custom script to check and uncheck the checkbox based on the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the Complete `ASP.Net MVC Kendo Tree View` Example [Here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/checkboxes).

The Problem might be `CheckChildren`. So just make it `false` to `true`. Like below.

```
.Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes
        .Name("checkedFiles")
        .CheckChildren(true)) // false to true
```

Make sure you have checked all the `child check boxes` of the parent. Then only the parent check box will be selected.

**Update:**

You may need the below code something like as well. `To make checked or unchecked`.

```
    .ItemAction(item =>
    {
        item.Checked = Model.Contains(item.Id);
    })
```

Comment: I have used the link that is shared above to create tree view and .CheckChildren(true) is not working as well.

Comment: I'm not clear what is going on in your code. But you may need to check / compare [Local-data-binding](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/local-data-binding) and [Check Boxes](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/checkboxes). See my update also

Comment: The only problem am facing is that when we check the parent node all the child nodes will be checked , which is perfect!
but when a child node is unchecked the parent is not unchecked which gives me wrong values while updating the count

Comment: Yes i'm clear on it. But not clear what is the problem happening inside the code. Because i never debugged your code.